# Strange CSS transition behavior on adding class

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, transition

[Class Event 1](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/vWKgoX?editors=1100) is what I am trying to achieve by just placing class  directly and not adding hover properties, though it's working for [Hover Elements](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/zPKgob?editors=1100).

Please check **[this](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/bYpOWx?editors=0110)** pen and you can find the problem by following the below instructions:

1. Type anything in the "*Name*"
2. Click `Tab`

You should reach the 1st State(Orange border on left and bottom and some transition effect), in which it pulls itself from the right corner, I don't understand why it's doing that. It working completely perfect in the [Hover Example](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/zPKgob?editors=1100) which is referenced above as well.

### Understanding of my CSS

```
.draw {

    transition: color 0.25s;
```

It gives an imaginary border of 2px transparent, which we will highlight later

```
  &::before,
  &::after {    
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
```

This is where you start the transition of `::before` from top-left corner

```
/*   This covers the top & right borders (expands right, then down) */
  &::before {
    top: 0;
    left:0;
  }
```

This will change the color of the text.

```
  &.dj {
    color: rgb(255,123,0);
  }
```

Here I want to expand it till 66% width.

```
/*  Class styles */
  &.dj::before,
  &.dj::after {
    width: 66%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

Is it mandatory to add/recommended `::after`?

```
  &.dj::before {
    border-bottom-color: rgb(255,123,0);
    border-left-color: rgb(255,123,0); // Make borders visible
    transition:
      height 0s ease-out, // Width expands first
     width 0.25s ease-out; // And then height
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a couple of differences between your hover demo and your tab implementation.

The first is that in the hover demo a left border is applied to `.draw:before` and a bottom border to `.draw:after`. In your tab implementation both borders are applied to `.draw:after`, and since `.draw:after` is aligned to the bottom of the button this messes up the vertical animation, which you actually want to start from the top and animate in a downward direction. This is fixed by giving `.draw:after` `top:0` instead of `bottom:0`.

The second problem is that you are applying the `.draw` and `.dj` classes simultaneously. As a consequence the border width and height is applied immediately. What you need to do is toggle between the width height start and end values. I suggest applying the `.draw` class directly to the button in your markup, and instead of toggling both classes, only toggle the `.dj` class when the user tabs.

Here is a forked pen with these changes applied: https://codepen.io/jnicol/pen/EbNavz

There are various other enhancements that could be made, but those changes should fix the immediate problem you have described.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking, and also can you please check the last part. i.e `draw2` class. I am trying to get the final transition as well. Thank you for the help.